# Distribution of distances between points with complete spatial randomness

Tags: probability, integration, summation

I'm trying to compute the *probability* of the distances between points on a 2D domain that have complete spatial randomness (CSR).  From [this wikipedia page on CSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_spatial_randomness), the probability of locating the $N$th neighbour of a point within a radius $r$ is

$$ P(N, r) = \frac{D}{(N - 1)!} \lambda^N r^{DN - 1} e^{-\lambda r^D}, $$

where

$$ \lambda = \frac{\rho \pi^{D/2}}{\Gamma(D/2 + 1)}. $$

Here, $\rho$ is the event density and $D ( = 2)$ is the number of dimensions.  However, what I ultimately want to calculate is, I guess, the integral of $P(N, r)$ wrt N, i.e.

$$ P(r) = \int_0^\infty \frac{D}{(N - 1)!} \lambda^N r^{DN - 1} e^{-\lambda r^D} dN = \frac{D}{r} e^{-\lambda r^D} \int_0^\infty \frac{\lambda^N r^{DN}}{(N - 1)!} dN. $$

Trouble is I don't know how to evaluate the integral.  I've tried using Sage's symbolic integration but to no avail.  Can anyone help?

---

Edit 1:

In light of joriki's comments, it might be useful if I added some more background to my problem.  What I have is $n$ points which are supposedly randomly distributed in the $(x,y)$ plane, as is shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezNxx.png) below:

[image: distribution of points on the plane]

I calculate the distribution of these points by 'binning' the distances between all pairs of points.  Finally, I want to compare this distribution ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJvnc.png)) to some theoretical distribution (hence my question on this forum).

[image]

---

Edit 2:

Following Ritz' comment, I tried taking the sum over $N$, such that

$$ P(r) = \frac{D}{r} \lambda r^D e^{-\lambda r^D} \sum_1^\infty \frac{\left(\lambda r^D\right)^N}{(N - 1)!}, $$

Or, using a change of variable, $x = \lambda r^D$,

$$ P(x) = \frac{D}{(x/\lambda)^{1/D}} x e^{-x} \sum_1^\infty \frac{x^N}{(N - 1)!} = \frac{D}{(x/\lambda)^{1/D}} x e^{-x} \sum_0^\infty \frac{x^N}{N!} = D x^{1 - 1/D} \lambda^{1/D}. $$

Clearly, this new function isn't going to describe the data in ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJvnc.png)).  What (to me) is curious is that the $P(N,r)$ function, if scaled and stretched, describes the data very well (imaging shifting the red curve over a bit and lowering its height).  Is this because I've misunderstood the meaning of this distribution?  Should it perhaps be the probability of *finding $N$ neighbours* within a radius $r$ and, actually, I'm only trying to find one neighbour at a time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by " the PDF of the distances between points"? And why do you think that you'll get a probability density function if you integrate $P(N,r)$ with respect to $N$?

Comment: If $D$ is number of dimensions, so I guess you should use Sum instead of integral.

Comment: @SAAN I don't want to sum over the dimensions, and I think the sum/integral over $N$ should cover all possible positive values rather than just a finite set.

Comment: You should sum over $N$ instead of take the integral; $N$ is an integer. Then use $\sum_{N = 1}^\infty \frac{x^N}{(N - 1)!} = x \sum_{N = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{N - 1}}{(N - 1)!} = x \sum_{N = 0}^\infty \frac{x^N}{N!} = x \mathrm{e}^{x}$.

Comment: @Dai Your equation based on Poisson Process hence follow Poisson distribution. Poisson Distribution is discrete one. So I believe Sum is the only solution. You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: @Ritz +1 Thanks, that solved part of my problem but then opened up a whole other part!

Comment: That's good. But read the other comments carefully as well. Make sure that you interpret $P(r)$ correctly. I don't immediately see what the correct interpretation is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're actually just calculating the probability distribution of $d(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are placed at random within a rectangle (square?).  Note that the pdf of the distance from a point to its $k$-th nearest neighbor doesn't depend on the size of the square, in the limit that the square becomes large, but what you're calculating certainly does.  The result (for a square of side $1$) is known to be
$$
f(d)=\begin{cases}2d(\pi+d^2-4d) && 0<d\le 1 \\
2d\left(-2+4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{d}\right)+4\sqrt{d^2-1}-\pi+d^2\right) && 1<d\le \sqrt{2},
\end{cases}
$$
if I haven't made any typos.  (For instance, see J. Philip's paper [here](https://people.kth.se/~johanph/habc.pdf).)

Comment: (+1) [Here's a picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1cAdh.png) showing the results of a simulation with $10^3$ pseudorandom points uniformly distributed on the unit square. The distances between all pairs of these points were collected for the plots on the right, in which circles show the histogram densities (relative frequencies divided by $\Delta d$) using bins of equal width $\Delta d=0.05$, for $0<d<1.4$ (plotted at the bin mid-points). The solid line is the pdf $f(d)$.

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks.  I have previously done exactly the same thing and the two distributions are *almost* identical.  My question is motivated by wanting to find the theoretical distribution behind this.